# Accessing this variable in addeventlistener function

Tags: javascript, dom-events

The JavaScript class is initiated as following

```
var add = new Add('2');
```

In `Add` class the constructor is written as:

```
add = function(a){
      this.abc = a;
}
```

Now, I have an `addEventListener` function as follows

```
div.addEventListener('mouseout', this.domouseout, false);
```

In `this.mouseout()` the `this.abc` is not accessible; how can I access the `this.abc` in the `this.mouseout()`?

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to the current object. Inside your Add object, `this` will refer to itself. Outside of your object, `this` refers to the current document. That's why `this.abc` doesn't mean anything outside of an object.

First, you could simplify your `addEventListener` by removing "this" before "domouseout":

```
div.addEventListener('mouseout', domouseout, false);
```

Then, in your `domouseout()` function, you can get `abc` by using `obj.abc`, where `obj` is an instance of your Add class.